# Dovecot without MYSQL

Tags: dovecot

I've been using Dovecot with passdb and userdb with MYSQL, but it's now putting an extra stress on the database, since I use IMAP and along with the daily hacking attemps, scanners and everything that connects to my port 993.

Since I don't have many accounts (around 130) I was thinking about ditching MYSQL and use a simpler way for authenticating, but it seems that the prefered way with dovecot is to use MYSQL. I couldn't find a real tutorial nor a helpful answer about it in SF. What would be the less impacting database on the system other than MYSQL? And how to do it?

Comment: I use `dovecot` without `mysql`; it simply authenticates off PAM, using regular user accounts.  The accounts in question have no valid shell, and `sshd` won't allow them to be used for authentication.  The consequent system load is very light indeed.  Is that out of the question for you?

Answer (score 1):

Using mysql is common but not required at all, there are [various authentication backends](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase) available. The default dovecot config doesn't use mysql, it authenticates via PAM (see MadHatter's comment)

However, it sounds like you're trying to solve your problem at the wrong place. If you get that many hacking attempts to affect your mysql performance you should probably reduce the load on the auth attempts, not on the underlying database. A common way is using [fail2ban](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/Fail2Ban) to firewall off IPs which try to brute-force your accounts.

Comment: I already use fail2ban =x there are days that my fail2ban.log's are almost hundreds of MB...

Comment: Besides, port 993 is for IMAP not MySQL so there's no point in changing MySQL to anything else. As suggested by @Gryphius you should make sure fail2ban is doing it's job correctly. I ban every 5 failed attempts in a 30 minutes time window for a whole 24 hours. Make more restrictions if you're still unsatisfied. For me I have found out that it's good enough. You can also [ban clients that are trying to send email to inexistant mailboxes](https://ychaouche.informatick.net/fail2banpostfix) (random mailboxes at your domain)